# org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I have a simple Java EE application that uses a stateless EJB, and a persistence object to perform a lookup on a table. I can deploy my application successfully to WebLogic 10.3 with Hibernate 4.2 and EJB 3.0 but when I run it I am getting an UnknownServiceException in my code on the line where I try to use and EntityManagerFactory to create an EntityManager instance. (I first tried to simply inject an EntityManager which was throwing a NullPointerException).

**Stateless EJB**

```
@Stateless
public class OrderLocatorBean implements OrderLocator
{

  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  public List<Order> getOrdersByDate(Date start, Date end)
  {
    EntityManager em = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<Order> queryByDate = em.createNamedQuery("findByDate", Order.class);
    queryByDate.setParameter("startdate", start);
    queryByDate.setParameter("enddate", end);
    List<Order> results = queryByDate.getResultList();
    em.close();

    return results;
  }
}
```

The EJB is packaged inside order.jar which is included in the ear file. Here is the **ejb-jar.xml** file for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
>

  <enterprise-beans>

    <session>

      <ejb-name>OrderLocatorBean</ejb-name>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

    </session>

  </enterprise-beans>

</ejb-jar>
```

Here is my **persistence.xml** file packaged inside order.jar in the META-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<persistence
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0"
>

  <persistence-unit name="Order" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>contexte-datasource</jta-data-source>
    <class>order.Order</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And here is the exception (last part of it) being thrown by the EJB:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1618)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getRawSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1207)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor589.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.deployment.EntityManagerFactoryProxyImpl.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryProxyImpl.java:96)
    at $Proxy238.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at order.OrderLocatorBean.getOrdersByDate(OrderLocatorBean.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:34)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:42)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy244.getOrdersByDate(Unknown Source)
    at order.OrderLocatorBean_43jnw0_OrderLocatorImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:39)
    ... 58 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by setting the hibernate configuration property hibernate.transaction.factory_class. See documentation here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-jta
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-dialects

I looked through the hibernate source and while I couldn't quite pinpoint the exact reason, I could see some initialization was failing. It looks like with weblogic (and maybe others) servers hibernate needs to know how to create JTA transactions. My updated files are below.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<persistence
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0"
>

  <persistence-unit name="Order" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>contexte-datasource</jta-data-source>
    <class>order.Order</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**Stateless EJB**

```
@Stateless
public class OrderLocatorBean implements OrderLocator
{

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public List<Order> getOrdersByDate(Date start, Date end)
  {
    TypedQuery<Order> queryByDate = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("findByDate", Order.class);
    queryByDate.setParameter("startdate", start);
    queryByDate.setParameter("enddate", end);
    List<Order> results = queryByDate.getResultList();

    return results;
  }
}
```